# css3 animation + slidetoggle don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

The airplane animation block (he flies from side to side - forever).

Block container can be collapsed and expanded using jquery:

```
onclick = "$('.wrap').slideToggle('normal'); return false;"
```

So, if you collapse and expand the block, the animation stops, how can I fix it?

Emulation for my question: 
http://learn.javascript.ru/play/eEkfi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the `.knopka` is pressed I think you need to call `go();` again:

**zminu HTML**

```
<div class="knopka">button minimize/maximize</div>
```

**i jQuery**

```
$('.knopka').on('click', function () {
    $('.wrap').slideToggle('normal', function () {

        // This is a callback function
        // put code here that you need to execute after sliding is finished

        go();

    });
    return false;
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wSVTc/1/)**

It's not perfect but I think you will get the idea.

Comment: There was one small question. If the unit will initially be rolled up, when you deploy the animation does not work. Again, need help.
http://jsfiddle.net/wSVTc/2/

Comment: Works. Last question, if I may. The block can be deployed in a collapsed state and, depending on the entered new user or page the old user. The new user unit initially deployed, the old user is minimized. How uches this nuance? How to merge work http://jsfiddle.net/wSVTc/1 + http://jsfiddle.net/wSVTc/3

Comment: I had a funny feeling you would ask this. I will try and take a look later today or after work so I will let you know if I can figure it out